# How to persist the login information after closing Browser using asp.net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When using the `ASP.NET` Identity, I want to persist the login information as long as possible when the user logs in to my website, so the user doesn't need to login again when they reopened their Browser (just like github.com and stackoverflow.com). When I login to github, it persists my information for many days, so I don't need to login again every day. Are there any methods can that can implement this functionality using `ASP.NET` Identity?

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the appropriate value to the `isPersistent` argument of the SignIn methods:

```
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("email@id.com", "password", isPersistent: true, shouldLockout: false);
```

or

```
SignInManager.SignInAsync(applicationUser, isPersistent: true, rememberBrowser: false);
```

The `isPersistent` argument is used to control if the user's authentication cookie should be persisted.

The `rememberBrowser` argument is used in case of Two Factor Authentication: a remembered browser can login directly with the password alone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `IsPersistent` property on `AuthenticationProperties` to persist login after browser close. The registered method `user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync` generates the new `ClaimsIdentity` to be refreshed in the cookie.

```
private async Task<SignInStatus> SignIn(User user, bool isPersistent)
{
    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent);
    return SignInStatus.Success;
}

public async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
{
    var userIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
       new AuthenticationProperties
        {
           IsPersistent = isPersistent
        },
        userIdentity
    );
}
```